# KVM guest access to host usb-serial dongle

Tags: kvm, serial-port

I have a KVM virtual machine running CentOS 7 on a host running Fedora 24. I have a usb-serial dongle (actually a RFID reader but that should really not matter) that is installed on the host. The host can see it after running:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1325 product=0xc02a
```

I have access to `/dev/ttyACM0` which is the device I need to talk to.

How do I can access to said device on the guest (CentOS 7) system?

Comment: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest - please write up an answer and accept it if this helps you solve your problem.  i'll upvote if it's a good answer (@ping me)

Comment: @cas: Not a super answer but it worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) suggested in a comment, you can use the [virt-manager GUI](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest) to do that:

[image: GUI]